# Connecting Firebase to Android application using Firebase authentication via email/password

Tags: android, firebase, framebuffer, fbo

I am trying to connect Firebase to my Android application using Firebase authentication via email/password. I am getting these errors:

> 2:16 PM    Emulator: FramebufferData::restore: warning: a texture is deleted without unbinding FBO
>
> 2:16 PM    Emulator: FramebufferData::restore: warning: a text
>
> 2:16 PM    Emulator: ure is deleted without unbinding FBO

Can you let me know what these mean?

This is my code :

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button buttonRegsiter;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.out.print("In main");
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    buttonRegsiter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerUserButton);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpassword);

    buttonRegsiter.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void registerUser(){
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email field is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter your 
            password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    //if validations are ok
    //show a progressbar

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering user...");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>
            () {
            @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task){
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed to register. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
              progressDialog.dismiss();
            }});
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == buttonRegsiter){
        registerUser();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think those warnings have anything to do with Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But everytime I try to register with email and password, it displays the toast 'Failed to register. Please try again.' I thought this is the reason. Can you help me out with this query?

Comment: Also, now when I am trying after disabling the touch sounds, I am getting an error that says -                                                                                    01-04 14:31:44.290 3734-3868/com.example.kinnari.trial E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.NullPointerException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfj.zza(Unknown Source)

Comment: Change your "Failed to register" toast to include `task.getException().getMessage()` to see the reason for failure.

Answer (score 0):

you delete the google-services.json file need to download again and place it on app file directori